# How to prevent IRB from asking to Display all possibilities?

Tags: ruby, irb

I've enabled tab-completion in IRB by adding the `require "irb/completion"` to my `~/.irbrc` file.

Now, IRB keeps asking me to type `y` before displaying the properties:

```
irb(main):001:0> 42.
Display all 112 possibilities? (y or n)
```

Is there some setting I can add to my `.irbrc` file to make the default behavior be to simply display all the possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since IRB uses GNU Readline, it can be also affected by contents of `~/.inputrc` file. You can get the behaviour that you described by setting these options in `~/.inputrc` :

```
set completion-query-items 0
set page-completions off
```

as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/601997/43811) on Super User.

However, this also affects Bash and possibly other programs using Readline, which may be either completely undesired annoyance, or a pleasant surprise :)